# Alternatives to multiple inheritance for a JSON model?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm consuming an API that returns a complex JSON object that looks something like this:

```
{
    foo1: int,
    foo2: string,
    someProp: string,
    objectProp: {
        foo1: int,
        foo2: string,
        someOtherProp: string,
        subObject1: {
            bar1: string,
            bar2: string
        },
        subObject2: {
            foo1: int,
            foo2: string,
            bar1: string,
            bar2: string,
            somethingElse: string
        }
    }
}
```

I'm working in .NET Core 2, so I'm using Newtonsoft.Json for parsing. I noticed that `foo1` and `foo2` were repeated, and so were `bar1` and `bar2`, so when building the model I decided to use inheritance to reduce the amount of code duplication, so:

```
abstract class FooObject
{
    public int foo1 { get; set; }
    public string foo2 { get; set; }
}

class BarObject
{
    public string bar1 { get; set; }
    public string bar2 { get; set; }
}

class ResponseObject : FooObject
{
    public string someProp { get; set; }
    public ObjectModel objectProp { get; set; }

class ObjectModel : FooObject
{
    public string someOtherProp { get; set; }
    public BarObject subObject1 { get; set; }
    public SubObject2Model subObject2 { get; set; }
}

class SubObject2Model : FooObject, BarObject // ERROR: CAN'T INHERIT MULTIPLE PARENTS!
{
    public string somethingElse { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any way around this, or am I just going to have to explicitly specify the `foo` or `bar` props on `subObject2`, thus duplicating code?

Comment: But is there a real inheritance between this object ? If not it is ok to duplicate code ... fx we have `City` and `Person` classes and they have `Name` property but there is no point of using common base class ... but if you wana do some common UI to show list of some classes with `Name` property you can use interface

Comment: It's a dumb model that only exists so that the program understands the shape of the JSON response - there's no functionality here, I'm not sure what you mean by "a real inheritance"? In my specific case, I have `id`, `created_by`, `updated_by`, `created_at`, and `updated_at` that reoccur together in like 6 places in the response, and `hash`, `ext`, `mime`, `width`, `height`, `size`, and `url`  that all reoccur together in about 4 places, and then one place that has all 11 properties. That's a lot of props to duplicate

Comment: by "real inheritance" i mean if `ObjectModel` is in fact a speciall case of `FooObject` or they just have only common properties

Comment: I would argue this an example of composition over inheritance, i.e. SubObject2Model **has** a FooObject, not SubObject2Model  **is** a FooObject. If you do not have control over the model, Do not try to force inheritance to avoid some minor duplication. Let the serialization object match as closely as possible to the json schema. If possible, generate the classes directly from the schema.

Comment: Yeah, it probably is real inheritance. The `FooProps` are ID and created/last updated metadata, which appears on most objects in the response, and the BarProps are image data - sizing, urls, and suchlike - which appears both as part of the `Image` property, and again in the various format definitions (`thumbnail`, `small`, etc) that are children of `Image`.

Comment: @JonasH Unfortunately, I haven't been given a schema, just access to the API, so I'm constructing this from sample responses

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're going to have to pick one of the object for inheritance or just not use inheritance. For inheritance issue, it might be argued that for minor deduplication of code, it is probably not worth it to use inheritance.

Now, an alternative route for accomplishing the deduplication would be to wrap the two sets of properties in an object. Shown here:

```
class ResponseObject : FooObject
{
    public FooObject foo {get;set;}
    ...
}

class ObjectModel
{
    public FooObject foo {get;set;}
    ...
}

class SubObject2Model
{
    public FooObject foo {get;set;}
    public BarObject bar {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

Of course, the json would have to match that format.

Comment: Alas, the json is from a third party and I have no control over it

Comment: Then, probably just need to duplicate a bit.

Comment: Related to the argument against inheritance, there are some good articles in the wild as to why inheritance can be a bit *evil*. https://medium.com/globant/inheritance-vs-composition-cfd48fd87e06
and https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/composition-vs-inheritance-how-choose

Answer (score 0):

You can use interfaces instead of inheritance.

Interfaces allow you to be more flexible. The code duplication in model not considered has a "real code duplication".

Code duplication only considered to be bad when it is involved in logic, so maintenance could go wrong, but when using interfacs you are forcing your model to be decoupled, so every change in the interfaces will raise an immediate compile time error in your model, so it is very easy to maintain in opposite to inheritance.

Comment: Yes. However, this doesn't get rid of duplication of code, just gives contracts.